# Set default options for inserting media

Tags: functions, hooks, options, customization

Is it possible to set default options for inserting image into article. I want every image to link to full image and be right aligned. Setting this manually every time is annoying and unproductive.

Can I do this with some hook in my functions file?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far to right align the image, for instance, the `img_caption_shortcode` filter? Does this need to work in MCE editor and on the live website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in two ways. If you want to keep it theme specific, edit your `functions.php` file with this code:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_new_default_image_settings' );

function my_new_default_image_settings() {
    update_option( 'image_default_align', 'right' );
    update_option( 'image_default_link_type', 'file' );
}
```

The other way to do it is more general, but also more rigid:

1. Go to YOURSITE.COM/wp-admin/options.php
2. Find the `image_default_link_type` field.
3. Type in `file`.
4. Find the `image_default_align` field.
5. Type in `right`.
6. Scroll to tho bottom and hit Save.

Some helpful references:

- WP Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference
- Credit for the technique: https://writenowdesign.com/blog/wordpress/wordpress-how-to/change-wordpress-default-image-alignment-link-type/

Comment: `image_default_link_type` has either `file` or `none` as its available options. Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that you can set it to a custom URL or the attachment page by default. I'm not really sure what you mean by "link to full image" but hopefully that works for you.

Comment: great solution, it works only for the new images, just as needed and it works from the MCE editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'default_image_settings_options' );
function default_image_settings_options() {
    update_option( 'image_default_align', 'center' );
    update_option( 'image_default_link_type', 'file' );
}
```

Comment: Some explanation why this is better/different from the accepted answer would be nice.

Comment: This runs an `UPDATE` on every page load. Not a great idea.