# Set default image link target in Gutenberg image block

Tags: images, javascript, hooks, media, block-editor

I want to set the *default* target of the image block in Gutenberg to "Media File":

[image: Link target]

I've found solutions for the [classic editor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/251429/set-default-options-for-inserting-media), and one that appears to work for [Gutenberg galleries](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/323224/138112) by editing the block's template, but I was under the impression that the intended way to modify the editor's behaviour is via JavaScript hooks in the block editor.

Is there a way to set the default target using a JavaScript hook in the block editor?

UPDATE: I made a pull request on the Gutenberg GitHub repository to try to implement the ability to override the default link target with a plugin. The latest version is [here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/17401). As of writing, this has not yet been merged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was (finally) fixed to Gutenberg (and will be applicable for both the image and the gallery blocks); and will add an option to WordPress options' database table.
this was done in
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/25578 and https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/25582

It'll be added to WordPress 5.6 but it's already available in the Gutenberg plugin.

To link the image to the file by default, issue the following in your theme or plugin:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', function() {
    update_option( 'image_default_link_type', 'file' );
});
```

Replace `file` with `attachment` if you want to link to the attachment page for some reason, or `none` if you don't want to the image to have a link.

As for javascript: modifying blocks so that they alter the site's options is possible in Gutenberg although I haven't gotten it to work yet, check out:
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/20731

Note that if you try do the image_default_link_type equivalent in javascript, don't use "file" and "post" as the options (as long as this ticket is open) - see https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/25587

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that too and verified it works. Finally it's supported!

Comment: FYI, this works for me~

Answer (score 4):

Using the filter `blocks.registerBlockType` we can alter block registration settings. We simply need to target the `core/image` block and modify the default value for the attribute `linkDestination` which is *none* by default.

```
function modifyLinkDestinationDefault(settings, name) {
    if (name !== "core/image") {
        return settings;
    }

    settings.attributes.linkDestination.default = "media";

    return settings;
}

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    "blocks.registerBlockType",
    "my-plugin/modify-linkDestination-default",
    modifyLinkDestinationDefault
);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks a lot! I wrapped your code in a `( function( wp ) { ... } )( window.wp );` block, and enqueued the script using the `enqueue_block_editor_assets` PHP hook. The enqueued script should have the `wp-hooks` dependency specified.

Comment: And, to set the default for galleries, you must modify the `core/gallery` block and set `settings.attributes.linkTo.default`. Gutenberg inconsistencies...

Comment: @Sean Im glad it worked. Thanks for the full explanation on how to enqueue to make use of the code. I don't think there is need to wrap everything inside a function, as we can use `wp` directly, which is already in the global scope (no need to include `window.`).

Comment: I've seen that wrapping code used elsewhere. Is it not there so that the code only runs when the window is initialised?

Comment: @Sean You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421911) for what is the purpose of wrapping functions in that way. When you use a script dependency enqueuing your own script, in this case `wp-hooks` as you indicated, you can then safely use the contents of that dependency in your script.

Comment: Update: unfortunately this solution doesn't actually work. The new default is set, but the `href` property is not - and this is required for the saved image to actually display the link. It seems that I actually have to somehow execute the [`onSetLinkDestination`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/a615ce6862545360ce6a463a5a7a5a17f71711f4/packages/block-library/src/image/edit.js#L193) function to set the `href`, but this can't be done until an image is actually uploaded (i.e. not possible on the `registerBlockType` hook). Any ideas for how this might be fixed?

Comment: @Sean Ive been looking into the different filters trying to find a way but I couldn't. As far as I understand there are two ways, modify the default attribute value of the block type (with the issue you point out) or update each block using [updateBlockAttributes dispatch](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/docs/designers-developers/developers/data/data-core-editor.md#updateblockattributes).

Comment: I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/13797) to implement this in Gutenberg which was later [improved by another user](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/14398)... if you need this feature, please poke the developers on those GitHub threads to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

The correct default attributes for linkTo in core/gallery it's that :

```
settings.attributes.linkTo.default = 'file';
```

Comment: Welcome to wpse! Consider adding more explanation about how to implement this code and what it solves, as it stands this cannot be considered a complete answer.